# Can you have untyped arrays on Asm.js?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

For example, is it possible to construct the following array on Asm.js:

```
var arr = [1,2,[3,4],"test"];
```

Comment: ASM is not really meant to be used with hand-written code...

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? This is for a compiler.

Comment: @dandavis: `asm.js` is a subset of JavaScript: http://asmjs.org/

Comment: i meant that i've not seen ASM code like that. You can't use strings with ASM, and i don't know about plain arrays either. it might accept them, but it would have to box the contents into a non-optimized internal, so i would stick with the subset types if possible. this one of those things that's easier to simply try than wait for an answer from the peanut gallery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. asm.js uses a single ArrayBuffer for its memory heap. It does not support nested arrays (although you can have overlapping typed arrays using the same buffer) nor strings. That said you could handle a c-style string yourself, but the asm.js module could only access it as bytes.